# Eclipse and EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have installed EGit plugin on my Eclipse Helios SR2 Installation. I also have a initialize a GIT repository in one of my projects. But unlike SVN EGIT doesn't show me visiual indications when I make changes to the source code. Why is this happening? Even after the GIT repository is initialized and a commit is made there are no visual indications at all.

PS: I have used the Terminal to initialize the repository, add files and make the initial commit.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used the terminal, then you have to tell Eclipse, that the project is a Git project and should be managed by EGit. You can do that by right-clicking on the project, then select Team -> Share Project, choose Git, and in the following dialog check the box "use or create repository in parent folder of project". Then in the column "Repository" it should show you a path like "../.git". Now finish and you should be done.

Comment: From above : "The Git label decorations can be switched on globally in the Preference Menu (Window > Preferences) under General > Appearance > Label Decorations."