# egit does not show label decorations

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am a git beginner.

I have created a git repository with 4 eclipse projects.

A while I was committing and pushing with the git command.

After that, I installed EGit for eclipse. In "Git repository exploring" perspective I added an "existing local repository" and I am able to commit and push changes from this perspective.

The problem is that, in any persective, eclipse does not decorate labels according to Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Label Decorations. Or more directly said - I cannot see uncommited changes in the project tree.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK I just saw the answer here:
[Eclipse and EGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055048/eclipse-and-egit?rq=1)

I had to manually add each of the eclipse projects right click -> Team -> Share -> Git -> Finish.

Why do these answers appear when you have just asked? :-)

Comment: That would be fine, but in Eclipse 2020-06 there are no  Team/share menu exists.